# How to create mongoose schema for category sub category management?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB Schema for handling category subcategory management where you can have multiple of subcategories from one root category. Basically for e-commerce system where user can add a product by selecting a category.

I have some requirements like:

- Fast retrieval of data from DB and easy insertion.

Please change according to you

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const {Schema} = mongoose;
import slug from 'slug';
import shortid from 'shortid';
const categorySchema = new Schema({
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    isDelete: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


categorySchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
    if (!this.slug) {
        this.slugify();
    }
    next();
});
categorySchema.methods.slugify = function () {
    this.slug = slug(this.firstName) + '-' + shortid.generate();
};


export default mongoose.model('category', categorySchema);
```

Please don't send any link to mongoDb docs

Comment: You need to be more specific about how your sub categories exist in DB, like are they embedded docs in category collection docs or do you've those in another collection and a reference exists between these ? something like that !! Or Do you need suggestions on defining mongo schema, Please keep in mind mongoose schemas are defined according to DB design,So you need to start with that, asking/presenting it here,Also not only for yours, everyone's priority for DB transactions is fast retrieval's & fast inserts-So users helping you here would know it & will definitely share you links if needed

Comment: I need suggestions on defining mongo schema for categories and subcategories where categories maybe like
**Electronics > Devices > Computer > Apple > Ipad**